# Which is the meaning of these masses?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, dark-matter, elementary-particles

When [reading](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0007165v1) about the masses of neutrinos in the HDM (Hot Dark Matter) model of the universe, I came across the following equation:

$$\tag{1} \sum_i m_{\nu_i} = 92 \Omega_\nu h^2 \text{eV}$$

My problem arises with the statement that follows: *"where the sum runs over all neutrino species with $M_{\nu_i} \leq 1$ MeV."*

This is written differently, solely as $m_\nu =  92 \Omega_\nu h^2 \text{eV}$ in [Sterile Neutrinos as Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287).

**The last equation makes it look like the mass of each individual neutrino must be $92 \Omega_\nu h^2 \text{eV} $(which sounds wrong to me as neutrinos of different flavours must have different masses) and the equation $(1)$ makes it look like that value is the mass of all neutrinos in the universe. Is this last interpretation the correct one?**

**If so, does the condition below it mean that the mass of each neutrino must be smaller than $1$ MeV or has it got some different meaning I am not understanding?**

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: This is about the individual mass of the various //types// of neutrinos, not about the summed weight of all neutrinos in the universe put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **sum** of the masses of neutrinos  that should be equal to the right side of the formula you quote, qualified that it is the low mass neutrinos that are considered, i.e. the [standard model neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) which are all of very small mass.

Comment: Then, does that condition, of $M \leq 1 \text{MeV}$ represent a limit of the mass of each individual neutrino?

Comment: Thats right.each individual standard model neutrino . High mass neutrinos are proposed in different models beyond the standard model, and they are not in the sum